# The purchase of 'ownership' of high-rep SO accounts?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone know of any offers for cash (or other real world compensations) for the right to call a high rep SO account their own?

How likely do you think such an offer has been or will be made?

I wouldn't think it likely but occasionally you hear about someone actually buying a powerful character on one of those online role playing games, so I wouldn't be too surprised to hear someone would attempt to do the same on SO (insert your own joke here about Jon Skeet and his ilk being characters and/or powerful).

Comment: I want to vote to close this, but non of the choices are appropriate. Can we have the "not a real question" option here on Meta?

Comment: Are you in the market?

Comment: More importantly, would ♦ accounts fetch a premium?

Comment: Also copied from the gaming world, I have a full time staff of Romanian programmers posting answers for me. In fact, they posted this comment.

Comment: A valid question considering a high rep might get you a job interview with the new careers site. "Man he couldn't write code in the interview, but shoot he's got 10k.  Maybe he was just nervous..."

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-to-convert-your-stackoverflows-reputation-into-money

Comment: I don't think this would make Jeff happy ...

Comment: Should this question be tagged [meta-tag:humor]?

Answer (score 9):

I will burninate people if they do this. Possibly along with their thatched roof cottage.

Answer (score 6):

Here are my rates:

- Vote to close a post: $5
- Edit a post to content of your choice: $20
- Rent 10K moderation tools: $100/hr
- Purchase account outright: $10,000

Comment: "We've already established what you are, madam.  Now we're merely haggling over price."  :D

Answer (score 2):

when is there going to be a Rent-a-John-Skeet-Account-For-a-Day just so the rest of us can see what it's like to have 100K rep? ;-)

Comment: Just spend every waking moment on SO providing detailed, well thought out, technically insightful answers to anything c# related. That should be a good simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is infuriating and obnoxious at first look... I am happy about the buzz factor SO has generated and the genuine glow it brings on a true contributor/member's face!

The actual act of helping out other developers and using SO as a learning tool ...itself...is a worthy achievement. Reputation points are just a side-show.

Any company worth its salt...would check/test/interview the prospect with utmost care ...and would do a good job gleaning the grains from the chaff.

Speaking of points..I almost always get this question...from friends,co-workers and bosses...who are introduced to the Reputation system here @ StackOverflow

It is usually in the realm of:
* One could always collude with multiple email IDs to jack up one's own points
* Multiple people could connive to help each other with point upheavals
...etc

This used to rile me up...at first; I mean any genuine,earnest member of this community would get angered.

Then on I've become tempered enough and usually counter these "statements" with..

"Yes, what you say is true! StackOverflow is just a microcosm of the real software world. But the probability of a High Reputation member being actually genuine is much higher than the real world.How many members in our team or our unit or our company...really deserve the pay they get...How many of them really KNOW the stuff...What could you do about Mr.XYZ who is basically dead-weight ... but is still a "Senior Analyst/Programmer/DBA/Architect"....!"

This answers sobers up most of the Doubting Thomases :)

**Fundamental Fact:** We as a community rock ! And shouldn't allow a bunch of fakers and another bunch doubters to spoil the fun we are having!!!

**Remember, those who CAN ... DO, others just mock or criticize!**