# Is there a way to hire somebody and pay them with Stack Overflow reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I would like to know if is it possible to hire somebody and pay them with Stack Overflow reputation, and moreover if it is legal according to Stack Exchange policy.

I am speaking about large amounts of reputation, much more than the 500 reputation cap of bounties.

Comment: Hire to do what exactly? If you want to get more attraction to your questions you can start a bounty on them.

Comment: Make sure to make it clear in your job offering that the time dedicated to producing a working solution to your problem will be rewarded with fake internet points, which can't be used in the real world to pay bills, buy groceries, etc. Seriously. This is the programming equivalent of "no dollars, but we're followed by X hundreds of people on YouTube so you'll get loads of publicity!!" job offerings for designers.

Comment: Very related with relevant answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133244/selling-stack-overflow-accounts

Comment: Sure @Jenayah my question was not about how to defraud somebody; my question was my question itself once both the parts have agreed.

Comment: Practically though, reputation has no real value outside the site it is on

Comment: @JourneymanGeek even on-site the reputation has dubious value. Some rep unlocks more privileges but there is only so much that's really useful to do. I personally draw the line at about 3k rep - close votes are the most useful thing, I find. Others may not even want that. Depends on how much moderation you're interested in. People might be perfectly happy with 1k rep to be able to see upvotes and downvotes, perhaps. So anything extra on top of the privilege you want is not really needed.

Comment: Will you photograph my wedding for exposure?

Comment: sorry @marcellothearcane , I'm a programmer not a photographer; maybe a programmer who does questions people doesn't like, but not a photographer anyway

Comment: It was an analogy. You would be hard pressed to find a photographer worth their salt that would not take real currency for a job. You get what you pay for!

Comment: This is OT @marcellothearcane . My question was about the possibility to use reputation as exchange value, not about how hard is to find somebody who accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a concrete question you need somebody to work on, and it's suitable for Stack Overflow (e.g. it's not too broad, like writing an entire program), you can post a [bounty](/help/bounty) as @NimeshNeema suggests. That even includes the advertising!

You are not allowed to 'pay' somebody with Stack Overflow reputation, neither by upvoting many of their posts (that would be [serial upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/295232)) nor by [awarding large bounties to their answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134477/295232). Voting and posting bounties needs to be done based on [the post content, not the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232).

Comment: Crystal clear !

Answer (score 3):

Did you chanced upon the bounty feature available in Stack Overflow as well as all the other Stack Exchange network sites. Consider going through this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

If you do not get a satisfactory answer to your question, you can offer a bounty which would be akin to what you are looking to do.

Only that offering a bounty doesn't guarantee that you'll get the answer, and the bounty points get deducted from your account as soon as you start one.