# Hours per reputation on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, reputation, stackapps

It occurred to me, with all the user data collected from the site.

Is there a way to calculate an estimation of the average number of hours a Stack Overflow user needs to gain 1000 rep?

There could be some formula to extrapolate how long it takes to type a post (not considering an research required to post); the user's visits and activity are logged.

It might even change as the user's rep increases.

Comment: We don't have the data. How do you know how long someone has been spending on SO (ie. number of hours)? Seeing someone every 10 minutes doesn't mean they have been on the site between sightings.

Comment: @Oded I understand this, but we could calculate the number of SO hours, ie spent reviewing, editing, posting.. not browsing and pls see my edit

Comment: The answer is 42 hours.

Comment: Hahaha @doubledown

Comment: This [question is cross-posted on stackApps](http://stackapps.com/questions/4221/calculate-hours-per-rep).

Comment: @AwesomePoodles I was hoping someone would make an app

Comment: I would make an app or a SEDE query, except that the required information is not available in either the API or SEDE.  I have also seen several people racking up huge scores with ho-hum, but fast, answers.  While thoughtful, more useful but slower, answers never catch up (at least on lower-traffic tags).  So time spent has no absolute correlation to reputation.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles very good observation, Can you post that as an answer pls?

Comment: No, I don't want to have to dig up the links to prove my claim. I've spent more time than I wished on this Q already (for no score).  ;-)

Comment: hey, apparently there's a real risk of rep being sold on the black market, you can go get some ;) hahahahahhaha (did you see that question?)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181153/whats-to-stop-someone-from-selling-their-reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be an interesting statistic.  However, as Oded alluded to, it would almost be impossible to properly determine, as I do not think the website monitors/has the ability to monitor the exact time interacting with the site, especially for activities such as reading questions/answers etc.

Also, I think if it were calculable, it would vary widely.

Comment: Widely, yes. Top users on SO usually accumulate between 2000 and 3000 reputation points *per week*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi very true, and occasional users like me would reach 1000 on this site in a few months, and SO in about a year.

Comment: @Damien I know it would not be an accurate thing, but it could show some trends?? please see my edit

Comment: @Yve yes, that is theoretically possible, but it would be a statistic of logged time, as there I no way of knowing exactly what the person is doing behind the keyboard.  It would also still vary widely.

Comment: @damien of course, but there would already be algorithms for how long it takes a person to write "x" number of words.. and the stats could be presented  as onsite time, plus time for typing.. excluding time for research and based on assumption that the answerer understood the question and answer and was able to type it without research

Comment: @Yve then there is the variable of typing speed. e.g. touch-typists vs. index-finger-keyboard-stabber

Comment: @Damien of course, but we can just use standard deviation and work out some algorithm.. for a user on a desktop/laptop with average typing speed bladdy bladdy bla

Comment: @Yve I see, yes, that is definitely possible, and as I said, would be interesting.  But to play devil's advocate and anticipate a possible question - why would we want this data?

Comment: @Damien because we are pedantic literal people and we can :) lol see my answer I posted  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181153/whats-to-stop-someone-from-selling-their-reputation/188768#188768

Comment: @Yve I can relate to that answer :)

Comment: @Damien I just answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725225/vs2012-missing-cmopiler-errors-in-error-list-after-upgrade-from-vs2010/17729303#17729303, in the comments I said I'd be a few minutes, 30 mins later I finished and posted my answer hahahahha