# Time Management Between the day-job and StackOverFlow - Serious Issue !

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, addiction, time

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do you escape an addiction to stackoverflow (or other IT sites)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21774/how-do-you-escape-an-addiction-to-stackoverflow-or-other-it-sites)
>   [You know you've been browsing Stack Overflow too much when?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11115/you-know-youve-been-browsing-stack-overflow-too-much-when)

guys,

I am not a hardcore StackOverFlow user like [Sir. Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) but I am seeing myself going into that direction. I am always distracted by this evil website *(I don't want to sound bad by saying evil but)* and I cannot control the time I am spending here lately.

This place is so informative (as well as it is that evil !) but I should keep going on my job as well.

So let's cut to the chase and get to the point.

Dear StackOverFlow'rs,

how do you handle the Time Management Between your day-job and StackOverFlow? do you schedule yourself to come here on a particular frequency or you just never leave here?

Comment: @YOU not totally similar I think :S

Comment: So he's been knighted now? (That would actually make just as much sense as Sir Nick Faldo.)

Comment: StackOverFlow? Where did that spelling come from? (And doesn't that prove you've not spent too much time on Stack Overflow at all? And what's up with the "guys"?)

Comment: @Arjan as you can read the beginning of the question : ***I am not a hardcore StackOverFlow user***

Comment: If that is your statement, then don't follow it with "like Sir. Jon Skeet", which totally changes the meaning of "not". Noise, I'd say.

Comment: @arjan then, I respect.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addiction

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-to-convert-your-stack-overflows-reputation-into-money

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do my work first, browse here second. Easy.

Comment: so, I am working between 09:00 am to 06:00 pm. that's pretty hard to stay away from here between those times.

Comment: @tugberk What I mean is that I make sure my work is done before I spend a lot of time on SE. It's just about personal discipline and work ethic. Block the sites with a browser addon if you have to, but put your job first.

Comment: thanks for the advice. that's a nice advice to block them. do you know any add-on for that kind of stuff. I'm in a feeling that I should really do that :S

Comment: @tugberk I've used StayFocusd for Chrome. There's something similar for Firefox, but can't recall what it's called. If all else fails, manually edit your `hosts` file. :)

Comment: installed the StayFocusd for Chrome. thanks for the tip :) ***BTW editing the hosts file is also good idea.***